# How to add new .java source file in Spring MVC project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I have copied a new .java file in relevant src folder. But, it doesn't appear in project explorer in STS4. No option in IDE to import file.

I know this is such a simple thing. Should have obvious options there. However I am not getting clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `F5` or execute the menu item `Refresh` on the project once you have added a file to the project from outside the IDE, like on the file system directly.